# click event not recognized in Firefox

Tags: angular, typescript, firefox, events, click

I have an Angular 2 site which is not completely working in Firefox. The problem is that it doesn't recognize the event that I pass into my typescript function. The event is a mouse click and the function is a mouse click event handler.

The html/angular code looks like this:

```
<div class="click-to-filter-outer" (click)="clickToFilter_Clicked(e)">
```

The typescript looks like this:

```
clickToFilter_Clicked(e) {
    $('.filter-panel').css('max-height', '500px');
    this.filterPanelState = this.filterPanelStates.EXPANDED;
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

The error I get in the Firefox console is:

```
TypeError: e is undefined
```

In all other browsers, I don't have to pass in the click event to the function. I can get it with a call to window.event like so:

```
clickToFilter_Clicked() {
    $('.filter-panel').css('max-height', '500px');
    this.filterPanelState = this.filterPanelStates.EXPANDED;
    window.event.stopPropagation();
}
```

What is the proper way to get the click event in a click event handler in Firefox running an angular site with typescript? If I'm doing it right in the above code, what could be causing it to say it doesn't recognize the event variable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your html template is of same  component.ts then,

### test.component.html

```
<div class="click-to-filter-outer" (click)="clickToFilter_Clicked($event)">
```

### test.component.ts

```
clickToFilter_Clicked(param1) {
/*---------------------*/
}
```

Or,

### child to parent communication - if event occurs in child and method is in parent.component.ts

### child.component.html

```
<div class="click-to-filter-outer" (click)="clickToFilter_Clicked($event)">
```

### child.component.ts

```
@Output() loadEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();

  clickToFilter_Clicked(param1): any {
    this.loadEvent.emit({ param1 });
  }
```

### parent.component.html

```
<child-cmp (loadEvent)=loadEvt($event)></child-cmp>
```

### parent.component.ts

```
loadEvt = ($event) => {
    this.clickToFilter_Clicked($event.param1);
  }

 clickToFilter_Clicked(param1): any {
   /* --------logic implementation----------*/
  }
```

Or,

### parent to child communication - if event occurs in parent and method is in child.component.ts

### parent.component.html

```
<div class="click-to-filter-outer" (click)="clickToFilter_Clicked($event)">
```

### parent.component.ts

```
 @ViewChild(childComponent)
  public child: childComponent;

  getChildMethod(param1): any {
        this.child.clickToFilter_Clicked(param1);
      }
```

### child.component.ts

```
 clickToFilter_Clicked(param1): any {
       /* --------logic implementation----------*/
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to capture the event object when declaring the event, you have to use `$event` instead of `e` like so:

```
<div class="click-to-filter-outer" (click)="clickToFilter_Clicked($event)"></div>
```

Further more, from the component side, you can use `e`, that won't cause any problem.